# Reading multiple items in data file C++

Tags: c++

I'm a C++ beginner.  I'm trying to read a file that is formatted like so:

5 Christine Kim       # 30.00 3 1

15 Ray Allrich         # 10.25 0 0

...

number string          # number number number

where each number has its own significance and the name does as well.  I can get the file open and read the first two items but after the name I can't get the numbers after.  This is my function right now:

```
void getItems( ifstream& dataFile,   // in file
            Employee item[],    // class array so I can store the data later
            int &transNum)  // number of transactions
{
     int id;             // employee ID
     char name[20];        // employee name
     double hourlyPay;   // pay per hour
     int numDeps;        // number of dependents
     int type;           // employee type

     transNum = 0;
     dataFile >> id;
     dataFile.ignore();                 // discard space before name
     dataFile.getline( name, '#');
     dataFile >> hourlyPay >> numDeps >> type;
}
```

I need it to read the first number, read the name, then read the last 3 numbers.  After every name (maximum 20 characters) there is a # symbol where we should stop reading the name.  I've tried adjusting the size of my char array for my string and other small fixes but nothing works. I realize that I will only get 1 line right now... I was just trying to get the first line to work before I made a loop to grab the other lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`istream:getline` needs a length parameter when used with a char array. Currently it is using '#' as the length value and using the default delimiter.
Change your code to

```
dataFile.getline( name, sizeof name, '#');
```

alternatively, use a std:string as the parameter to getline, then you don't need to specify a maximum size.

Comment: Ok.  I modified my getline line but now the 3 variables after (hourlyPay, numDeps, and type) come out very funky.  Their values are -9.25596e61 and -858993460

Comment: Note that this solution leaves whitespace before and after the name.

Comment: @KwakKwak I tried it out and it seemed to work for me - the hourlyPay etc variables were filled out correctly.

Comment: It worked for me after I made one minor change.  I had to adjust the size of name to 21 (to include the space) to make it work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close.  The problem is likely to be the line

```
dataFile.ignore();
```

By default, `ignore` ignores everything [up to EOF](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/).  What you want to do instead is ignore up to some number of characters until the next space.  So that call would instead be:

```
datafile.ignore(100, ' ');
```

Where 100 is a purely arbitrary choice of number.  Substitute your own rational value.

Next is your use of `getline` which must be told how many characters to read.  Since your buffer is 20 characters, you need to inform `getline` like so:

```
getline(name, 20, '#');
```

Comment: For what it's worth, instead of using 100, you could use `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()`. From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/: "If this is exactly numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), there is no limit: As many characters are extracted as needed until delim (or the end-of-file) is found."

Comment: @vmrob: Yes, that's the way I'd do it, but the OP is a beginner who isn't even using `std::string` yet, so it seemed to me that an arbitrary constant whose function is explained might be of more use.

Comment: Good points! I'm inclined to dislike the current teaching methodologies, being a student myself, but I totally agree with the concern. If it were up to me, I would start teaching things like `vector`, `string`, and all that jazz far before I got to pointers and references.